# PHP does not store all variables in session

Tags: php, session

I'm assigning session variables by filling the $_SESSION - Array throughout my script. My problem is, that for some reason not all variables are available in the session.

here is a shortened version of my code for explaining this issue:

```
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);

$_SESSION['lang']        = 'de';
$_SESSION['location_id'] = 11;
$_SESSION['region_id']   = 1;

$_SESSION['userid'] = 'eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3';
$_SESSION['hash']   = 'dce57f1e3bc6fba32afab93b0c38b662';

print_r($_SESSION);
```

first call prints something like this:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [lang] => de
    [location_id] => 11
    [region_id] => 1
    [userid] => eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3
    [hash] => dce57f1e3bc6fba32afab93b0c38b662
)
```

the second call prints:

```
Array
(
    [lang] => de
    [location_id] => 11
    [region_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [lang] => de
    [location_id] => 11
    [region_id] => 1
    [userid] => eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3
    [hash] => dce57f1e3bc6fba32afab93b0c38b662
)
```

As you can see, the important login information is not stored in the session.
Does anybody has an idea what could be wrong with my session? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Do you happen to be using variables named `$userid` and `$hash` elsewhere in the script?

Comment: Does the same call occur in the same script? Before the second call to print_r do you by any way unset Session variables? Do you use a component or library that might be using the same hashes for user authentication ('userid' and 'hash') ? (make sure you have globals disabled)

Comment: I use many different scripts. but the first print_r is at the very beginning, right after session_start(), and the second print_r is followed by exit()

Comment: I have the same problem, could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Further expanding on what Pekka might be alluding to, if you have register globals on there may be a naming conflict with your session variables and other variables in your script. If possible turn register globals off or rename your variables they don't collide ($_SESSION'hash'] and $hash) and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I renamed the variables to some arbitrary value, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code, untouched, in a single script and run it several times. You should get the same results the 2nd, 3rd, 4th... time.

```
<?php
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);

$_SESSION['lang']        = 'de';
$_SESSION['location_id'] = 11;
$_SESSION['region_id']   = 1;

$_SESSION['userid'] = 'eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3';
$_SESSION['hash']   = 'dce57f1e3bc6fba32afab93b0c38b662';

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

If it works, then you obviously have something wrong in your script that you are not posting. In that case you should provide more code in order to be able to help you.